# convert array of JSON objects to hash map using lodash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I need to convert

```
var data = [
{ rel: 'links-A', href: 'url1', id: 0},
{ rel: 'links-A', href: 'url2', id: 1},
{ rel: 'links-B', href: 'url3', id: 2},
{ rel: 'links-B', href: 'url4', id: 3},
];
```

to a hash map like this:

```
var converted = {
linksA: [
        {href: 'url1', id: 0},
        {href: 'url2', id: 1}
                 ],
linksB: [
        {href: 'url3', id: 2},
        {href: 'url4', id: 3}
        ],
}
```

Not sure if it's doable with lodash

Comment: Must you remove the `-` in property names? If not can use `_.groupBy(data,'rel')`

Answer (score 2):

First [**groupBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) rel and then map across the keys using [**mapKeys**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapKeys) to remove the hyphen:

```
var converted = _(data)
    .groupBy('rel')
    .mapKeys( (v, k) => k.replace('-', ''))
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to use lodash if you don't want to. The `.reduce` array method should be sufficient:

```js
var data = [
{ rel: 'links-A', href: 'url1', id: 0},
{ rel: 'links-A', href: 'url2', id: 1},
{ rel: 'links-B', href: 'url3', id: 2},
{ rel: 'links-B', href: 'url4', id: 3},
]

var converted = data.reduce((final, current) => {
  var newKey = current.rel.replace("-", "");
  if (!final[newKey]) final[newKey] = [];
  final[newKey].push({href: current.href, id: current.id});
  return final;
}, {})

console.log(converted)
```